# How to apply plotting with matlines to a list of data frames

Tags: r, plot, apply, lapply

I am hoping to apply a plotting function to a list of data frames and save to a designated folder. I'm able to plot the points, but am unable to determine how to apply the matlines to each corresponding plot. Data frame `a` in the plot command below is a single data frame in a list `ds1`. `m` in the `matlines` command is a single list of mcarrays within a larger list `model.one` for each of 40 samples.

```
structure(list(X = 271:279, RunTime = c(110.7456193, 10.29555673, 
23.64595448, 36.49562995, 47.69554832, 60.24535378, 72.49592154, 
84.59610247, 94.04568292), rad = c(0L, 112L, 180L, 272L, 351L, 
430L, 482L, 541L, 609L), value = c(233.2387405, 209.8006377, 
212.0638549, 215.3483471, 219.3000462, 223.5726513, 228.6726164, 
233.3633682, 237.0504306), ID = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), coefficients..Intercept. = c(281.6626635, 209.8700852, 
207.1099171, 201.5211056, 196.3326852, 194.8341761, 192.8200506, 
199.4736392, 182.1788075), coefficients.x1 = c(-0.437317635, 
0.022265912, 0.20820413, 0.375518671, 0.479472476, 0.480583864, 
0.497020482, 0.400718379, 0.586395654), R.squared = c(0.954030672, 
0.355701698, 0.857345184, 0.948827169, 0.967127094, 0.954887542, 
0.946878654, 0.93366159, 0.958896684), std.error..Intercept. = 
c(1.049993511, 0.08559681, 0.18204786, 0.299970875, 0.404005375, 
0.609778088, 0.832852025, 0.886205157, 1.123158853), std.error.x1 = 
c(0.009696988, 0.010763137, 0.008579099, 0.008809366, 0.008929516, 
0.010551842, 0.011891828, 0.010789815, 0.012263946), Date = 
structure(c(18155, 18155, 18155, 18155, 18155, 18155, 18155, 18155, 
18155), class = "Date")), row.names = 271:279, class = "data.frame")

str(m)
List of 7
 $ alpha: 'mcarray' num [1, 1:2000, 1:16] 0.00581 0.0057 0.00545 0.00231 0.00372 ...
  ..- attr(*, "varname")= chr "alpha"
 $ beta : 'mcarray' num [1, 1:2000, 1:16] 0.000555 0.001245 0.000348 0.000402 0.000165 ...
  ..- attr(*, "varname")= chr "beta"
 $ Pmax : 'mcarray' num [1, 1:2000, 1:16] 1.36 1.84 1.13 1.56 1.15 ...
  ..- attr(*, "varname")= chr "Pmax"
 $ R    : 'mcarray' num [1, 1:2000, 1:16] -0.446 -0.499 -0.418 -0.166 -0.359 ...
  ..- attr(*, "varname")= chr "R"
 $ mu   : 'mcarray' num [1:9, 1:2000, 1:16] -0.4463 0.0474 0.2311 0.3891 0.468 ...
  ..- attr(*, "varname")= chr "mu"
 $ sigma: 'mcarray' num [1, 1:2000, 1:16] 0.103 0.0973 0.0997 0.0972 0.0957 ...
  ..- attr(*, "varname")= chr "sigma"
 $ mu.pr: 'mcarray' num [1:81, 1:2000, 1:16] -0.446 -0.39 -0.336 -0.285 -0.236 ...
  ..- attr(*, "varname")= chr "mu.pr"

plot(coefficients.x1 ~ rad, a, pch = 16)
matlines(I.pr, t(apply(m$mu.pr, 1, function(x) c(mean(x), quantile(x, c(0.025, 0.975))))), 
lty = 1)
```

What I would like to do is use the above code to generate 40 (all samples) individual graphs to look like the one below. I have tried the following with no success:

```
lapply(ds1, function(x) {
  plot(coefficients.x1 ~ rad, x, pch = 16)
  matlines(I.pr, t(apply(model.one$mu.pr, 1, function(x) c(mean(x), quantile(x, c(0.025, 
0.975))))), lty = 1)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have destroyed your `dput`. Don't touch it, just copy and paste. Case you tried to subset the output, don't. Subset before evaluation, e.g. `dput(data[1:20, 3:40])`. Please try again.

Comment: Hmm, not really sure what went wrong. Tried to copy and paste again. Hope this works!

Comment: Still not working though for me, tried it out?

Comment: Ah, there was a rogue "." in the Date column. Should be good to go now. Sorry about that.